# Chrome is really slow to empty my listbox via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I allow a user to search a listbox which narrows results contained in said listbox.

The ajax request is fast to return the results and chrome is able to add the results quickly. The problem lies in the middle step where I actually empty the listbox.

Here's the code:

```
function PopulateListBox(data, listBox) {

    var options = '';
    if (data != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += "<option value=\"" + data[i].Id + "\">" + data[i].Name + '</option>';
        }
    }
    listBox.empty().append(options);
}
```

where data is a JSON array and listbox is a a jquery selector with the ID for a listbox (the selector is by ID e.g. `$('#listbox')`. There are about 5-10k options in the listbox.

Firefox and even IE handle this well but Chrome is stuborn (what happened to the "fastest js engine" google??).

I'm using the latest jquery (1.5.1) and Chrome 11.0.696.3 dev. (I'm also using FF 3.6 and IE 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity did you try `replaceWith`? ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) here.)
You'd need to have a div wrapping up your listBox, and that'd be the one you pass in to the `PopulateListBox` function. You'd also need to manually wrap the `options` variable with the listbox opening and closing tag info (shown below as pseudo html):

```
...
options = "<listbox tag>" + options + "</listbox tag>";
listBoxWrapperDiv.replaceWith(options);
...
```

Comment: Chrome handled this solution like a champ! Thanks bantic

Answer (score 2):

It might be faster to use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of `empty()` followed by `append()`:

```
listBox.html(options);
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. It does make the code cleaner though so I'll use that method anyway unless there is a faster way. I also tried `listbox.children().remove()` to empty the listbox but that was no help either. They all cause chrome to lock up and ask if I want to wait or kill the pages.